# Obtain ToTraceString() for IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities

I use

```
  `.....
   .....
  query = query.Where(criterion, fiedNames);
  string sql2 = ((ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString();'
```

to obtain and tweak SQL code that is going to be executed by LINQ.

When I do quick watch I get the following SQL statement which i do not understand.

```
SELECT [UnionAll2].[C3] AS [C1], [UnionAll2].[C4] AS [C2],
[UnionAll2].[C5] AS [C3], [UnionAll2].[C6] AS [C4], 
[UnionAll2].[C7] AS [C5], 
[UnionAll2].[C8] AS [C6], 
[UnionAll2].[C9] AS [C7],  
..... few hundereds line more.....
@p__linq__4 AS [C2], 
.....
CASE 
     WHEN ( [Join5].[id] IS NULL ) THEN 
     Cast(NULL AS INT) 
     WHEN ( @p__linq__0 = 1 )

.......
```

Obviously if i paste in SQL management studio and execute it will throw me errors if i do not pass the value for `@p__linq__0`....

My question: how can get trace SQL that can execute on SQL management?

Comment: Actually, your sample looks like valid SQL to me.  Obviously the `@p__linq__4` stuff would have to be passed in a la an SP param, but otherwise, that all looks totally legit.  (is it ugly?  yes, that's the tradeoff you make when using an ORM)  Also, what's the actual SQL error?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in SQL other than that i have to pass those parameters (i have not idea), so is there a way or need a tweak to do in order for not to generate `@p___linq___0`? my api do render data without providing the parameters and those parameters are optional.

Comment: What I'm asking is what error did you get (i.e. "it will throw me errors") when you tried executing the SQL in SSMS?

Comment: i will correct what i said in my post but what i was trying to say that it will throw me errors if i just copy and paste the sql meaning without passing the parameters.

Comment: Right!  But what is that error!? :)

Comment: Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 217
Must declare the scalar variable "@p__linq__0"

Comment: Ah, so yeah, in that case, you should just declare some SQL variables in your sample when trying to execute it.  i.e.  `declare @p__linq__0 varchar(200) = 'foo'`  Though I have no idea what SQL type `@p__linq__0` is actually supposed to be.  But my guess is that your problem has nothing to do with the SQL that is being generated per se, but something else.  What actual error do you get in your C# project when running your code?

Comment: I'm not getting any error in C# project the whole purpose of tracing is to find out what sql statement is generating so that i can execute the same sql statement and see the result.

Comment: Ok, then yeah.  Here's the rub:  When invoking dynamic SQL via EF, the ORM (EF) generates a SQL string that will be invoked using a prepared-statement.  All input variables for that SQL statement are inputted via prepared-statement idioms, and all such input will manifest itself in the literal SQL via declared parameters such as `@p__linq__0`.  If you actually want to "try out" that SQL, you are going to have to mock those input parameters as local SQL variables (using `DECLARE`) in order for you to actually try it out.

Answer (score 1):

This extension method you can assert:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Traces IQueryable's DB query />
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">IQueryable type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="query">The IQueryable query</param>
    /// <returns>Query</returns>
    public static string ToTraceString<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        var objQuery = query as ObjectQuery<TEntity>;
        if (objQuery != null)
        {
            sb.AppendLine();
            if(objQuery.Parameters.Count > 0)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("Query parameters:");
                sb.AppendLine("--------------------------------------------------------------");
                sb.AppendLine("      Name          |        Type        |       Value        ");
                sb.AppendLine("--------------------------------------------------------------");
                foreach (var param in objQuery.Parameters) 
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0, -20}|{1, -20}|{2, -20}{3}", param.Name, param.ParameterType.ToString(), param.Value, Environment.NewLine);
                }
                sb.AppendLine();
            }

            string partialQuery = objQuery.ToTraceString();
            objQuery.Parameters.ToList().ForEach(p => partialQuery = partialQuery.Replace(":" + p.Name, p.Value.ToString()));

            sb.AppendLine(partialQuery);
        }

        // replace 

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: after i implement the above method i dont see any diff, what exactly will be doing the above extension?

Answer (score 1):

```
   public class LinqProvider<T>
    {
        static readonly FieldInfo INTERNAL_QUERY_FIELD;
        static readonly FieldInfo QUERYSTATE_FIELD;

        static LinqProvider()
        {
            INTERNAL_QUERY_FIELD = typeof(DbQuery<T>).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals("_internalQuery"));
            QUERYSTATE_FIELD = typeof(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<>).BaseType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "_state");
        }

        public IQueryable<T> QueryContext { get; set; }

        InternalQuery _InternalQueryContext;
        public InternalQuery InternalQueryContext
        {
            get
            {
                if (_InternalQueryContext == null)
                {
                    _InternalQueryContext = new InternalQuery();

                    if (QueryContext is DbQuery<T>)
                    {
                        var internalQuery = INTERNAL_QUERY_FIELD.GetValue(QueryContext);

                        var objectQueryField = internalQuery.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals("ObjectQuery"));

                        _InternalQueryContext.ObjectQueryContext = objectQueryField.GetValue(internalQuery) as System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<T>;
                    }
                    else if (QueryContext is System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<T>)
                    {
                        _InternalQueryContext.ObjectQueryContext = (QueryContext as System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<T>);
                    }
                }

                return _InternalQueryContext;
            }
        }

        public LinqProvider(IQueryable<T> queryContext)
        {
            QueryContext = queryContext;
        }

        public class InternalQuery
        {
            public System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<T> ObjectQueryContext { get; set; }

            public string ToTraceString(IDictionary<string, object> Parameters = null)
            {
                var state = QUERYSTATE_FIELD.GetValue(ObjectQueryContext);

                var mi = state.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "GetExecutionPlan");

                mi.Invoke(state, new object[] { null });

                var paramState = state.GetType().BaseType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "_parameters");

                if (paramState != null)
                {
                    System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameterCollection col = paramState.GetValue(state) as System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameterCollection;

                    if (col != null && Parameters != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in col)
                        {
                            Parameters.Add(item.Name, item.Value);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return ObjectQueryContext.ToTraceString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the extension method name to TraceString2, for example, because TraceString is the same  ObjectQuery method name.

This extensión, show all data of query parameters (@p_*linq*_0 ...):

```
using (var context = new MyEntities(true))
{
    string cpty = "MiCpty";
    DateTime date = DateTime.Today;

    var query = context.CECA_SPECIAL_CAS.Where(a => a.IDACUERDO == cpty 
                                                    && a.FECHAENTRADA == date);
    query.ToList();

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(query.ToTraceString2());
}
```

result:

### Query Parameters:

### Name          |        Type        |       Value

p_*linq*_0          |System.String       |MiCpty
p_*linq*_1          |System.DateTime     |31/10/2013 00:00:00

SELECT 
"Extent1"."IDACUERDO" AS "IDACUERDO", 
"Extent1"."NOMBREPRINCIPAL" AS "NOMBREPRINCIPAL", 
"Extent1"."NOMBRELEGAL" AS "NOMBRELEGAL", 
"Extent1"."NOMBRELARGO" AS "NOMBRELARGO", 
"Extent1"."FECHAENTRADA" AS "FECHAENTRADA", 
"Extent1"."DIASEMANAOPERAR" AS "DIASEMANAOPERAR", 
"Extent1"."TIPOCONTRATO" AS "TIPOCONTRATO", 
"Extent1"."PERIODICIDAD" AS "PERIODICIDAD", 
"Extent1"."DESC_PERIODICIDAD" AS "DESC_PERIODICIDAD", 
"Extent1"."ACTIVO" AS "ACTIVO", 
"Extent1"."MA_TYPE" AS "MA_TYPE", 
"Extent1"."MA_VERSION" AS "MA_VERSION", 
"Extent1"."COLLATERALPORTFOLIOCODE" AS "COLLATERALPORTFOLIOCODE"
FROM "CKCOL_ADM"."CECA_SPECIAL_CA" "Extent1"
WHERE (("Extent1"."IDACUERDO" = MiCpty) AND ("Extent1"."FECHAENTRADA" = 31/10/2013 00:00:00))

Answer (score 0):

You can see the executed query with the sql server 2008 tool 'Sql Server Profiler'.